# Mixing time of personalized PageRank random walk

Tags: graph-theory, mixing

Suppose I have a weighted graph $G$, and let $M$ be the Markov chain corresponding to a random walk on $G$. Let $t_{\text{mix}, M}(\epsilon)$ be the $\epsilon$-mixing time of $M$.

Now let $M'$ be the "personalized PageRank" random walk on $G$, which I define below, with restart probability $r$. Let $t_{\text{mix}, M'}(\epsilon)$ be the mixing time on $M'$.

Is there any relation between $t_{\text{mix}, M'}(\epsilon)$ and $t_{\text{mix}, M}(\epsilon)$?

EDIT: I probably should be more clear about what I mean by a personalized PageRank random walk on $G$. Fix a set of vertices $v_1, ..., v_n$ and $r \in (0,1)$. Suppose you are at vertex $w$. Then:

- with probability $1-r$, you move to the next state in $M$, as you usually would
- with probability $r$, you teleport to one of $v_1, ..., v_n$, picked uniformly at random.

Comment: this markov chain is on a graph? what is random walk with restart?  do you have the textbook?

Comment: yeah for simplicity, let's just say the markov chain is on a graph. i changed the terminology to "personalized PageRank", which I edited to include a brief definition of. does this make the question clearer?

Comment: is this from Amy Langville's book by any chance? if you don't get an answer here try cs.stackexchange.com or cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: no, this is just a problem I'm encountering right now in some work. and thanks for the suggestion about where to ask though--cstheory is probably a better place.